# Node js => SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Hi when i try to run my node file in vs code terminal give me this:

> node index.js
>   Thrown:
>   node index.js
>        ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: We can't guess what the exact problem is but you have code that is invalid and cannot be interpreted or executed. Withut seeing the code, it's impossible to say. However, *please* do make an effort to solve it yourself first - the error message should point you towards the line number and what's wrong. Questions about simple typos like missing brackets are closed as they don't help other readers.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to not having the required imports according to your nodejs version 
Check this link it explains about the ESM imports for nodejs 12
https://thecodebarbarian.com/nodejs-12-imports